# Problem with image on the main page Magento 1.8, Php 7.0

Tags: magento-1.8, migration, 404, php-7, media-images

Migrated Magento from one server to another and update PHP from 5.4 to PHP 7.0. I have image inside a product page, but don't have images on the main page

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
/:100 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_1_1_2.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_1_1_1_1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://xenergo.net/ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/CZK.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_1_1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/NOK.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_uliczna_001_tdziwna_1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/GBP.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/u/n/untitled_1_wince__2_1_1_1.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/u/n/untitled_1_wince__2_2.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/u/n/untitled_1_wince__2_1_1.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/u/n/untitled_1_wince__2_1.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/u/n/untitled_1_wince__2_1_1_2_1.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/2/x/2x7w_600mm.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_3.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/CHF.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Try to inspect those images using your browser's web developer tool. Check the images URL's and post the the URL example here. Also, try to open some product from the list in the admin panel and click "Save" just to resave the product. Check if the image appears on the main page after.

Comment: did you reindex after import the images?

Comment: Yes I'am reindex (twice) system - index managment - reindex all

Comment: Also I try resave image and add new image  its didnt help me :(

Comment: When I do inspection I have this mistake:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
xenergo.net/:100 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
https://xenergo.net/ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_1_1_2.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://xenergo.net/ledstore/talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://xenergo.net/ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/CHF.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://xenergo.net/ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/SEK.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://xenergo.net/ledstore/ntend/default/jm_flannel/images/currency/CZK.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, change url in admin panel magento solved my problem

Comment: Maybe you want to add this as an answer and accept it :) Just to note ... there are other issues related to PHP7, so please consider using recommended extension from below.

Comment: If you who found the answer, please answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

In admin panel **Flush Catalog Images Cache** from

```
admin > Sytem > Cache Management > Flush Catalog Images Cache
```

also check if your media has appropriate permission. The default permission for magento are as below

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

Comment: I Flush Catalog Images Cache but its didnt help me

Comment: `<your magento root dir>/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43bc35/l/a/lampa_office_001_t.resized_1_1_2.png` have you does image exists in above path.

Comment: Yes, I have an images there.

Comment: But i found that when I used "inspection " I see a problem with link: talog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43b    must be catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/180x180/8e014dfe9f6c69941cf952d49a43b

Comment: Which skript i mast edit that to solve the problem?

Comment: I assume there are custom block called in your homepage. You can open template hint from backend and check the phtml and block that are being called.

Comment: Its strange people give negative vote if solution dint work out for them. This resolves issue to many who face image issue.

Comment: I stile cannot found an answer on my problem  :(

Comment: @userpk just read your comment. IMHO if an answer didn't work for the given question it's OK to downvote (just meaning answer wasn't helpful in THIS case). In general i'd like to see more votes. UPs for questions with some research effort or questions that could affect many users. For answers, if the could really answer the question. DOWNs for 1-line questions w/o any research effort and answer that 1) do not fit 2) are copies of already given answers 3) are wrong b/c question wasn't read carefully.